# how to display iframes with sites from a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, iframe

Hi guys I'm trying to somewhat of an autosurfer and for the life of my I cannot figure out how to use iframes on my site to display all of the sites I have in my mysql database. Now all of the website urls are stored in a column in my table in the database, so I assume I'll need to assign them to an array. But my main problem is getting them to display each site for fifteen seconds then load a different one. I understand iframes for the most part, but I don't get how to get it to show a site, refresh show another, etc. I also can't figure out how to load the sites into an array for the iframe to use. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What's not working on `$q = mysql_query(...)`, `while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $q)){...}` ?

Comment: you can do this only with javascript  , try changing the href of the iframe every 15 sec.

Comment: I might actually be scripting my array incorrectly, i'm not sure. Thats the problem...I dont' really know what I'm doing ha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use JavaScript to refresh your iframe.

Let's say this is your iframe:

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

You'll need to use JavaScript to do the refresh, and AJAX if you want it to get data from your database. So do something like this in a javascript file (I'm using jQuery):

```js
$(function(){
    function refresh_iframe(){
        $.get('iframe_url.php', function(data){
            // set iframe src to the url that the php gave us
            $('#iframe').attr('src', data);
            // run this function again in 15s
            setTimeout("refresh_iframe()",15000);
        });
    }
    // run the first time
    refresh_iframe()
});
```

Then in `iframe_url.php` you'd have something like:

```js
    <?php
            $q = mysql_query("SELECT `url` from `iframe_urls`");
            $results = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
            $key = array_rand($results);
            echo($results[$key]['url']);
    ?>
```

Comment: This looks great let me try it out and I'll let you know.

Comment: For some reason it isn't refreshing. I assumed I would just put the javascript code into the body of the webpage that would have the iframe on it. Was i wrong?

Comment: You'll have to include jQuery, and the javascript should be in `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tags, or preferably in an external .js file.

Comment: Ok. So i would just use an include function to use the external .js file in the current webpage? And I am getting a php error when using the iframe_url.php page. It says: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a7161583/public_html/iframe_url.php" On the first line where $q is.